# How to use App.config in WPF application for log4net configuration

Tags: c#, wpf, log4net, app-config, rollingfileappender

Currently im working on a WPF version of an existing console application.
In the console application i use log4net to do all my logging.
Therefore i configured all my appenders etc in the App.config file.
Everything works fine in the console application.

Now i want to implement the same logging functionality in my WPF application.
I have to say that im totally new in WPF and this is my first WPF project.
I just tried to add the App.config (exactly the same one) to my WPF project as i had it in my console application.
But it does not work. No files are created by the FileAppenders. But i also dont get any error or warning when compiling.

What do i have to do to get the same logging functionality for log4net as in my console app?
How can i configure log4net (Appenders) in an WPF application?

Thx in advance

xxxxxx Edit xxxxxx

Based on Roberts hint i could solve it.
I added

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()
```

to my Main Window. Now my logging works exactly in the same way as it does in my console application.

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        // check if Application is already running
        // if it is running - Kill
        if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)).Length > 1) System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Comment: do you call log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() on startup?

Comment: I've added the answer so that solution is clearly visible

Comment: I have called log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure() but its not working. Please help me .. you have any log4net.config file in your project @ck84vi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to call `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure()` on startup.

Answer (score 2):

its simple, inside `Window Constructor` just add this line like this

```
public MainWindow()
{       
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); 
    InitializeComponent();
    //.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the way you do it a bit more in detail

```
using System.Windows;
using log4net;

namespace Namespace
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for App.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
        //Log.Info("Hello World");
        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
}
}
```

Don't forget to add log4net into the the configSections in your App.config

```
<configSections>
  <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,Log4net" />
</configSections>
```